# Запись аудиоданных в существующий аудиофайл, используя FFmpeg API

Tags: c++, кодировка, ffmpeg

Моя главная задача заключается в том, чтобы по запросу клиента, записывать полученные аудиоданные в **уже существующий файл**.

В качестве примера предположим, что я уже создал аудиофайл с длительностью аудиозаписи 1 час. Я хочу открыть его, записать дополнительный 1 час аудиоданных и закрыть его. В результате мы должны получить аудиофайл, содержащий 2-часовую звуковую дорожку. Я правильно понимаю, что в этом случае, если это возможно, мне придется удалить предыдущий записанный трейлер (он был записан благодаря функции [av_write_trailer](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/group__lavf__encoding.html#ga7f14007e7dc8f481f054b21614dfec13)), записать полученные данные в конец файла, а при закрытии аудиофайла записать текущий трейлер ?

Это фрагмент кода, где я записываю трейлер и закрываю медиафайл:

```cpp
// Writing the stream trailer to an output
// media file and free the file private data.
av_write_trailer(p_oFrmCtx);
avformat_close_input(&p_oFrmCtx);
```

---

Важно отметить, что реализация записи аудиоданных в новый аудиофайл работает отлично. Проблема заключается именно в том, чтобы записать аудиоданные в существующий аудиофайл.

Comment: Возможно это... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33109284/how-to-get-ffmpeg-to-append-to-existing-ouput-file-and-not-overwrite-it поможет. Реализацию параметров - можно в либе найти.

Comment: @nick_n_a спасибо большое за комментарий. Я уже просматривал этот вариант, но к сожалению, у меня нет столько времени, чтобы углубиться в реализацию библиотеки. Оставляю это на самый крайний случай.

Comment: @bbdd, а есть цель оптимизировать запись на диск в случае, если первое аудио всё равно придётся считывать или нет? И есть ли возможность считать первое аудио полностью и держать его в памяти до момента завершения объединения?

Comment: С чего вы решили, что там есть какой-то трейлер, который надо удалять? Вы хоть пробовали писать аудио файлы один за другим в один файл?

Answer (score 1):

В поставленном общем виде у этой задачи нет решения. Возможность дописать данные в существующий файл по сути невозможна для большинства аудиоформатов поскольку предполагает сочетание множества факторов: структура файла должна предполагать возможность дописывания с или без необходимостью совпадения форматов данных существующей и новой части; реализация соответствующего контейнера должны быть явно адаптирована к склейке; в большинстве случаев реализация будет предполагать считывание всего имеющегося фрагмента прежде чем первый байт может быть дописан, часто в т.ч. с использованием временного промежуточного файла/потока.

Из числа традиционных форматов данных существует лишь небольшое количество примеров, таких как MPEG TS, где принципиально предусмотрено дописывание. Стандартно склейка происходит из уже готовых кусков и путем полномасштабного пересоздания файла с копированием данных.

Comment: Ну в принципе можно подрезать хвост и точечно поменять метадату и что там ещё есть по длительностям и подобному. Естественно, при условии, что сжатие одинаковое.

Comment: Вопрос поставлен о реалистичных вариантах ("используя API"), а не о фокусах, каждый их которых будет 100% специфичен к каждому отдельно взятому формату. Так что нет. И, самое главное, стандартные реализации форматов изначально не предусматривают такие варианты использования, существуют лишь точечные примеры манипуляции данными такого плана.

Comment: Многие форматы ffmpeg может выводить потоково в stdout - выбираем любой такой формат и к нему дописывать уже точно можно. Только в конце файла может быть какой-то хвост, который надо снести - не знаю, есть ли подходящее api у ffmpeg, чтобы определить позицию этого хвоста, но почему бы ему не быть? Ну и надо в конец дописать верный хвост, учитывающий обе части - вот тут вполне могут быть сложности. Но в целом кажется разумным.

Comment: @RomanR. полностью с вами согласен, по поводу того, что в принципе, это не возможно. Но что вы скажете на счет того, если при закрытии файла, не записывать так называемый трейлер. И после того, когда вновь придется записывать новые данные (естественно, с такими же параметрами и кодеком, как это было реализованно до этого), просто записывать их в конец файла. Разве, у FFMPEG нету что то подобного, как FILE_SEEK ? Важно отметить, что все те же аудиоданные будут записываться, как и раньше, а именно с тем же кодеком, частотой дискретизации, битрейтом и так далее.

Comment: @Qwertiy, в моей реализации, я могу использовать лишь Matroska формат

Comment: @bbdd, я не в курсе, что это за формат. Можно команду для ffmpeg, которой можно получить такой файл из другого?

Comment: @bbdd, кстати, до меня дошло, что раз ты сам используешь api ffmpeg'а для записи, то ты сам пишешь и завершающий хвост, а значит можешь заранее сохранить его позицию в соседнем файле, а потом просто делать truncate. А вот насчёт формирования нового хвоста для объединённого файла по-прежнему есть сомнения.

Comment: Все это возможно чисто теоретически, с стиле академических рассуждений. Практической возможности такому нет. Даже в вашем примере если файл не закрыт сначала (без трейлера), то второй сессии необходимо иметь потерянный контекст от первой сессии. Такая возможность не входит стандартную функциональность. Кроме того, чтобы оформить это в качестве API от него бы потребовалось также выполнять ряд проверок на соответствие формат и т.п. Этого просто нет. Не потому что невозможно в принципе, а потому что выходит за стандартные рамки.

Comment: @RomanR., а как стримминговые сервисы работают, когда клиент может подключиться с любого места?

Comment: Что касается конкретно MKV у меня есть *educated guess*, что технически - в грубом варианте - это возможно потому что я делал что-то близкое (дописывал бесконечно новые аудиоданные и броузер этот поток также бесконечно играл), но я сомневаюсь в то, что это достижимо посредством libav/FFmpeg.

Comment: @Qwertiy они не обмениваются файлами. Файлы, за редким исключением, это законченные куски данных без возможности incremental appendage.

Comment: Тогда я не вижу другого выхода, кроме как записать новые аудиоданные в медиафайл с тем же именем, что и исходный, но с тегом, например `part_1`, `part_2`, `part_n`. Пример данных файлов: `file.mka`, `file_part_2.mka`, `file_part_n.mka`.

Comment: Да, так (с возможной потом отдельной склейкой кусков), или - если у вас нет требования, чтобы новая повторная запись началась мгновенно - при повторной записи создаете новый файл, но перед тем как туда что-то записать, читаете все из предыдущего и вписываете, вычисляете какую дельту по времени надо будет добавлять к новым данным, и потом продолжаете писать новые, а старый файл удаляете. Можно и так.

Comment: @RomanR. Я думал об этом, но медиафайлы в моем проекте могут достигать длительности до 1 месяца (не спрашивайте, кому нужны такие аудиофайлы, я сам был в ступоре), что при использовании, например, аудиокодека `Opus`, это сумасшедший размер. Я не говорю уже о необработанных аудиоданных `L16`, так как это вообще за гранью универсальности. В определенных условиях, `L16` может занимать размер в 10 раз больше, чем `Opus` кодек, с такой же продолжительностью.

Comment: По сути это задача для специализированной библиотеки, возможно на основе `libmatroska`, чтобы реализовать такую функцию с учетом имеющихся ограничений и для данного формата. Такая узкоспециализированная библиотека могла бы появиться (т.е. задача выглядит реалистично в такой формулировке). А средствами даже `libmatroska` не говоря уже о более высокоуровневых как `libav` так сделать едва ли выйдет.

Comment: @bbdd То, что формат - матрешка, стоило бы указывать в самом вопросе. И параметры кодека и контейнера тоже.

Comment: Решение есть, другое дело, что готового решения может не быть, а писать самому это довольно затратно. За автора такую задачу никто не решит. А если у кого-то кто прочёт вопрос - такое решение и есть, то захочет ли он поделится... сложно сказать.

Comment: Вообще сырые mpeg данные можно спокойно записывать друг-за-другом (при условии vbr - непостоянная частота дискретизации), оно хорошо ляжет, прийдётся только "обвёртку" правильно обновить и всё. Сделать это можно или руцями, или возможно через либу. Поэтому... гипотетически это решаемо.

Answer (score 1):

Предложу решение в лоб - записывать в формате MP3.

Формат MP3 состоит из простых блоков, которые склеиваются между собой без особых проблем.
Но есть определенные требования к исходным данным:

1. Частота и число каналов должны быть одинаковыми, чтобы потом не было проблем с воспроизведением.
2. Настройки кодирования желательно сделать одинаковыми.
3. Рекомендуется использовать постоянный битрейт для корректной навигации по полученному файлу.
4. Отключите запись тега id3v2 и блока Xing, т.к. они будут создавать мусор в местах склейки.

Примерное решение через командную строку:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input1.wav -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k -write_xing 0 -id3v2_version 0 ouput1.mp3
ffmpeg.exe -i input2.wav -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k -write_xing 0 -id3v2_version 0 ouput2.mp3
ffmpeg.exe -i input3.wav -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 192k -write_xing 0 -id3v2_version 0 ouput3.mp3
COPY /B ouput1.mp3 + ouput2.mp3
COPY /B ouput1.mp3 + ouput3.mp3
```

Если надо написать на C/C++, то возьмите за основу официальный пример [encode_audio.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/encode_audio.c), поменяйте кодек на MP3, пропишите свои параметры кодирования (тут могут быть сложности с доп. параметрами, т.к. в примере отсутсвуют) и пишите в бинарный файл, открытый в режиме добавления `fopen(filename, "ab")`.

PS: Блок MP3 имеет фиксированную длительность (26,1 мс для 44100 Гц, 24 мс для 48000 Гц), что может иметь значение в некоторых сценариях использования.